# CRUD with pure JS on a List, no API/AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a table, Manifest. I want to display the manifest for a particular job to the user, and let them Create, Update, and Delete on their manifest, on one page using JS. I want to do this without an api or ajax because, frankly, I can't wrap my head around it. It's probably the better way to go. But another project, not today.

I have successfully displayed the List of existing manifest items to the view. I have a table with  inputs for each existing value. I have the "remove" button for each to delete the corresponding row. I have the JS to add a new, blank row to the table. And I have the "submit" button to post the data.

However, when I submit, it doesn't seem to pass/save any new records that I add to the table, and I'm not sure why. For the [HttpPost], I chose to delete the existing records, and then rewrite them into the db.

My question is why doesn't the new row data pass/save to db.

I would appreciate any help or advice.

The view [truncated slightly for easy viewing]

```
    @model List<AURA.Models.Manifest>

    <h4>manifest</h4>
    <form action="Manifest" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.zero" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float:right" />
    <br />
    <table id="tableToClone" border="1" cellpadding="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                
                <th style="width:30px">
                    TYPE
                </th>
                <th>
                    DESCRIPTION
                </th>
                <th>
                    WRAP?
                </th>
                <th>
                    ASSEMBLY?
                </th>
                <th>
                    NOTES
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr id="rowToClone" style="display:none;">               
                <td style="width:30px">
                    <input type="hidden" name="zero" value="@ViewBag.zero" />
                    @Html.DropDownList("manifests.Type",
                        new SelectList(new List<Object>
                        {
                            new { value = "L", text = "Large"},
                            new { value = "S", text = "Small"},
                            new { value = "H", text = "Hand"},
                            new { value = "F", text = "Fragile"},
                        },
                        "value",
                        "text"
                        )
                        )
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("manifests.Name")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("manifests.Wrap",
                        new SelectList(new List<Object>
                        {
                        new { value = "FALSE" , text = "NO"  },
                        new { value = "TRUE" , text = "YES" },
                        },
                        "value",
                        "text"
                       )
                    )
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("manifests.Assembly",
                   new SelectList(new List<Object>
                        {
                        new { value = "FALSE" , text = "NO"  },
                        new { value = "TRUE" , text = "YES" },

                        },
                        "value",
                        "text"
                       )

                    )
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("manifests.Notes","")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btRemoveRow" value="REMOVE" onclick="RemoveRow(this)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            @*@foreach (var item in Model.Manifests.Where(p => p.Type != "B" && p.Type != "C"))*@
            {
                <tr>
                    
                    <td style="width:30px">
                        @Html.Hidden("manifests[" + i + "].Id",
                            Model[i].Id,
                            new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                        @Html.Hidden("manifests[" + i + "].Zero",
                            Model[i].Zero,
                            new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("manifests[" + i + "].Type",
                            new SelectList(new List<Object>
                            {
                                new { value = "L", text = "Large"},
                                new { value = "S", text = "Small"},
                                new { value = "H", text = "Hand"},
                                new { value = "F", text = "Fragile"},
                            },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            Model[i].Type
                            )
                            )
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("manifests[" + i + "].Name", Model[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("manifests[" + i + "].Wrap",
                            new SelectList(new List<Object>
                            {
                            new { value = "FALSE" , text = "NO"  },
                            new { value = "TRUE" , text = "YES" },
                            },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            Model[i].Wrap
                           )
                        )
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("manifests[" + i + "].Assembly",
                       new SelectList(new List<Object>
                            {
                            new { value = "FALSE" , text = "NO"  },
                            new { value = "TRUE" , text = "YES" },
                            },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            Model[i].Assembly
                           )
                        )
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("manifests[" + i + "].Notes",
                            Model[i].Notes,
                            new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="btRemoveRow" value="REMOVE" onclick="RemoveRow(this)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Add Row JS" id="btAddF" style="float: left" onclick="addRow()" />
    <script>
    function addRow() { 
            var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
    
            var table = document.getElementById("tbody");
            var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
            clone.style.display = "table-row";
           
            table.appendChild(clone);
        }
    
        function RemoveRow(text) {
            var cell = text.parentNode;
            var row = cell.parentNode;
            $(row).remove();
        }
    </script>
```

and the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Manifest(List<Manifest> manifests, string zero)
    {
        //string zero = "111111-1";

        //delete existing
        foreach (Manifest ListManifest in manifests)
        {
            //for existing
            if (!(ListManifest.Id == 0))
            {
                var existing = _context.Manifests.Find(ListManifest.Id);

                _context.Manifests.Remove(existing);
                //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

            Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
            manifest.Zero = zero;
            manifest.Type = ListManifest.Type;
            manifest.Name = ListManifest.Name;
            manifest.Wrap = ListManifest.Wrap;
            manifest.Assembly = ListManifest.Assembly;
            manifest.Notes = ListManifest.Notes;

            _context.Add(manifest);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: IMHO I do not think that it is possible to send dynamically added rows during your `form` submit. This is because your `View` code is rendered first by the engine and it has not way to know if you added/deleted any items in your `form` section so you would explicitly have to get the values of the added items in your `JS` and then use `AJAX` to post it to the `Controller`. You can follow this tutorial for your purpose: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Pass-send-dynamically-added-HTML-Table-records-list-to-Controller.aspx

Comment: When you click `submit` button, Is there any error message show in Console with F12?

Comment: @RahulSharma i think you deserve the answer here. post and i can give it to you

Comment: I think you will have to use an API call to make the changes to the database. It seems complicated, but it's really not, even without a library to use. Not to mention a necessary skill for pretty much any web developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I do not think that it is possible to send dynamically added rows during your form submit.

This is because your View code is rendered first by the engine and it has no way to know if you added/deleted any items in your form section so you would explicitly have to get the values of the added items in your `JS` and then use `AJAX` to post it to the Controller.

You can follow this tutorial for your purpose: [Tutorial Link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Pass-send-dynamically-added-HTML-Table-records-list-to-Controller.aspx)